# Different user settings for synced sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've [synced](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing) my User folder with sublime settings.

But what if I want to use different settings for different machines? For example, in settings of [terminal](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal) package I define path to Git Bash, and it's

```
"terminal": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe"
```

on one machine, and

```
"terminal": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe"
```

on another.

I've tried to use default settings, but they refresh all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into this package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageSync
I've never used it, but according to the README,

> PackageSync provides the following user configurable settings:
>
> ...
>
> **ignore_files [array]**
>   The list of files to ignore when backing up.

So you would want to create a `PackageSync.sublime_settings` file that has this in it:

`{
    "ignore_files": "Terminal.sublime_settings"
}`

This isn't ideal since it prevents the enitre file from syncing, not just that one entry (the `"terminal": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe"` entry), but it should work. (Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself)

---

### **Alternative: Possible workaround**:

You could also just use the line `"terminal" : "~/my_custom_terminal_shortcut"` in your settings and then create a `~/my_custom_terminal_shortcut` file on each computer that links to the appropriate location